# Cocos2d-x setVisible doesn't work

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm making messagewindow. And I wanna controll each letter.
I ran Sprite#setVisible to controll each letter but it doesn't work.
Label#setVisible works normally.

Here is my code.

```
void MessageWindowLayer::setText(std::string& text) {
this->message = text;

Label* msgLabel = Label::createWithTTF(message, "fonts/JKG-L_3.ttf", 24);
msgLabel->setPosition(cocos2d::ccp(0, back->getContentSize().height));
msgLabel->setAnchorPoint(ccp(0, 1));

this->runAction(CallFunc::create([msgLabel]() {
    int num = msgLabel->getStringLength() + msgLabel->getStringNumLines() - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        Sprite* letter = msgLabel->getLetter(i);
        if (nullptr != letter) {
            letter->setVisible(false);
            log("isVisible:%d", letter->isVisible()); // isVisible returns "0" but letters still show
            //letter->runAction(
            //  Sequence::create(
            //  DelayTime::create(0.2f*i),
            //  //JumpBy::create(0.5f, Point::ZERO, 60, 1),
            //  Show::create(),
            //  NULL
            //  ));
        }
    }
}));

parentLayer->addChild(msgLabel);
}
```

thank you.

EDIT:
I changed cocos version "3.8 final" to "3.7.1", it become worked.
So I opened issue on github.

Answer (score 1):

ttfLabel is not support 'getLetter()' if you want tu control every letter,you need to use bmfontLabel

Comment: 'getLetter' is working I guess, because when I try run action 'JumpBy', It worked